Android 14: (SeekBar) onDraw is protected now
In my Android app I am overriding AppCompatSeekBar.onDraw to extend my seek bar.
As far as I know this is the way it should be done - see: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-drawing
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    canvas.drawLine(...)  // drawing an additional line
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}

But now Google forces me to update to Android version 14 (API level 34) where onDraw is protected. See AbsSeekBar.onDraw: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
The error message is: "'onDraw' overrides nothing".
What is the preferred way now to extend this widget?
Or what do I have to change so that my app works again with Android 14?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I just created a class that extends AppCompatSeekBar to try and was able to override onDraw without any error
